# How to use std::for_each?

Tags: c++, algorithm, foreach

Is it possible to use std::for_each or anything else like that ?

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

// Class declaration
//
struct Interface
{
   virtual void run() = 0;
};

struct A : public Interface
{
   void run() { std::cout << "I run class A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public Interface
{
   void run() { std::cout << "I run class B" << std::endl; }
};

// Main
//
int main()
{
   // Create A and B
   A a;
   B b;

   // Insert it inside a list
   std::list<Interface *> list;
   list.push_back(&a);
   list.push_back(&b);

   // Then execute a func with for_each without recreate a func which call Interface::run() 
   std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), run);

   return 0;
}
```

Edit :
My question is : How can I call each run() member function inside a loop using algorithm or a more simply a C++ way without using iterators...

Comment: `Interface a = new A;` This doesn't even compile. What, precisely, are you trying to do?

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: Sorry, I've write a little code to show only what I want to do. Basically I want to call the member function run inside a loop using for_each or something else. I know I could use iterator but I ask myself if there was an other way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using `std::mem_fun`:

```
std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), std::mem_fun(&Interface::run));
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew about `mem_fun`. +1

Comment: `std::mem_fn` is the correct function with C++11, `std::mem_fun` is deprecated as it only works for 1 (or 2?) argument functions.

Comment: You can also use `std::bind` in C++11

Comment: Just remember it's deprecated in C++11 for `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia nope, that will not work here, because you need it to be bound once for each iteration to each item in the list. That's what I thought too (and deleted my answer)

Comment: @Seth: `std::bind(&Inerface::run, _1)`, what's the problem?

Comment: @Xeo fffffFFFFFFFffffffff... I just read five seconds ago about `std::placeholders`... You guys know everything.

Comment: Well, std::mem_fun work perfectly. Actually I'm currently working on an old standard so I don't have the deprecated problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I come back to you to ask a little clarification, what if I wanna give some args using std::mem_fun ? I think it's an other question but maybe you'll can easily give me a tuto or something else ?

Comment: @kl94: Yes, that's a different question with a wider variety of answers. I suggest opening a new question, you'll get better answers.

Comment: @Xeo: A missing `t` is the problem!

Comment: @Lightness: And you didn't even think of telling me that 9 hours ago, eh?! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way would be to use a lambda function:

```
boost::for_each(list, [](Interface* i){ i->run(); });
```

Other options include:

```
boost::for_each(list | boost::adaptors::indirected, std::mem_fn(&Interface::run));
```

and

```
boost::for_each(
    list | boost::adaptors::indirected,
    std::bind(&Interface::run, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your participation but I don't use boost in this project. I upvote you despite all.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to create a wrapper function that will call `run()` on whatever object is passed into it. C++ doesn't have the sort of dynamic dispatch that will allow you to use a string to refer to a function and look it up at run time - what gets called in for_each has to be one and only one function at one address, not a polymorphic function.

You don't have to create a wrapper function for every object: you just have one, and it gets called repeatedly and passed in the object. Then you call run() on the passed in object, and polymorphism does the rest:

```
void wrapper(Interface* obj)
{
    obj->run();
}

std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), wrapper);
```

Comment: Of course I can do that, but what if I have 30 member func to call ? I've to create 30 wrapper funcs.. ? I don't think it's a good way just for call one func =/ What do you think ?

Comment: @Matt You'd be storing things in the list as pointers, not values, so the signature for wrapper should be `void wrapper(Interface* obj)` (and also not `const` because `run` is not `const`)

Comment: @kl94 no you just call the 30 member functions in the wrapper one after another. Then those calls will be executed on each item in the list.

Comment: Good catch, @Seth. Updated my answer - and I see the list declaration has been updated too. All is right in the world :)

Comment: @Matt I don't see how you can call an other member func inside your wrapper without redefine an other wrapper, can you put an exemple plz?

Comment: No worries. I think it got downvoted before I added clarification that only one wrapper function was needed. Fast responses sometimes yield unclear answers sometimes yield downvotes.

Comment: It's basic polymorphism: the run() that gets called on obj will be whatever run() is relevant for obj, regardless of the dynamic type. So this will get called 30 times, and if obj is _really_ an A, A::run() is called. If it is _really_ a B, B::run() gets called. The reason you can't just use `run` in for_each is that it needs the _address_ of a function, not the _name_ of the function (roughly). It's not calling `run` on whichever object is being iterated on, it's calling `operator ()` and run _cannot_ be resolved to objects when for_each is declared - it must be resolved _on every iteration_

Comment: @Matt I think you didn't understand my question (or maybe I don't understand well your answer.I ask about what if you have a, for example, 30 member functions like run(), run_loop(), start(), test(), lol() etc. Do I have to create 30 wrapper to use all of these members functions using your methods ?

Comment: AHA! Ok, you're right, I didn't catch that. Yes. with my scheme, you would - and so @Greg's mem_fn is a far better answer for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Taking Matt's example, but making it generic:

```
class wrapper : public std::unary_function(Interface*, void) {
  void (Interface::*pmf)();
public:
  wrapper(void (Interface::*pmf)()) : pmf(pmf) { }
  operator()(Interface* intf) { intf->*pmf(); }
};

std::for_each(ist.begin(), list.end(), custom_wrapper(&Interface::run));
```

If you need to support arguments, derive from `std::binary_function(Interface*, T, void)` and store the `T` alongside `pmf`